# How to know the population distribution at the limit with a Leslie matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

So I have a Leslie Matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}0&3&1\\1/2&0&0\\0&7/10&0\end{bmatrix}
And I'm asked to find the population distribution at the limit. (how the poppulation stays after a lot of years).

I can't find it in any textbook nor the internet, I only find how to do it with Markov 2x2 matrices.
Since I've seen a few exercicies like this in past exams I really need to understand it.

Comment: Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_matrix, the dominant eigenvalue  gives the population’s asymptotic growth rate and the corresponding eigenvector the stable age distribution. Incidentally, I found this in short order by simply searching for “Leslie matrix” and looking at the top hit.

Comment: I really struggle to understand it (english is not my native), could you please use the example I've shown to explain it?